# Do 5G cellular kits than are connected to SBC, support encryption when the signal goes via them to the wifi?

Tags: wifi, gsm

I have seen around some 5G cellular kits that can be connected to SBC (Single Board Computers) in order to make a WIFI hotspot. From the one side, they provide 5G cellular connection and from the other side, they support WIFI connection.

Do the SBC continue to provide security to signals coming from the 5G cellular side and guided to WIFI side? Can someone who controls the SBC decrypt the 5G signal?

Comment: ... the encryption used on the cellular side is very, very different from the encryption used on the WiFi side, so, yes, there is a point where the traffic is unencrypted (at the signal level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the SBC continue to provide security to signals coming from the 5G cellular side and guided to WIFI side? Can someone who controls the SBC decrypt the 5G signal?

There's no *signals* guided from one side to the other. There's IP packets that's routed or forwarded from one side to the other. The IP packets *has* to be in clear text for the router to be able to handle them.

This is layer 3 in the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). In addition data can be encrypted *inside* the IP packets, for instance using TLS. This will be unaffected by your router; it happens at higher layers.

Encryption over the waves (or wire in case of cabled interfaces) happens at L1-L2 in the OSI model.